# MaterializeCss not working on ios

Tags: ios, materialize

I have a website built with materializecss. Its working flawless on windows or android platforms but its not working properly on ios. Does anyone know about this problem?

I mean by not working is not having pictures loaded and all tabs opened one under another etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this sites written on [materializecss framework](http://materializecss.com/).

- http://www.absurdoburger.com.br/
- http://www.straphq.com/
- http://explore.visitsarasota.org/visitsarasota
- http://softvar.github.io/
- https://stamplay.com/
- http://closeheat.com/

All sites work great on my Iphone 5s (safari)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "all tabs opened under one another". Could you paste your code? We've managed to make it work great on http://closeheat.com.